# nmcli not working on Ubuntu 16.04 for Huawei E3372

Tags: usb-modem, modem-manager, 4g

I have created a VM Ubuntu 16.04 on windows 7 host. I connected the 4g modem. The ifconfig give the following additional interface

```
enx0c5b8f279a64 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 0c:5b:8f:27:9a:64
```

which works fine and have internet access via 4g network.
Apart from that I need to get additional cellular data from modem like MNC,MCC, signal strength etc, but don't want to get from the relevant web api. So I tried to get them via ModemManager mmcli but I got the following printout when giving

**Output of command** `mmcli -L`

```
No modems were found
```

**Output of command** `lsusb`

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 12d1:14dc Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd.
```

**Output of command** `dmesg`

```
[    2.386168] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    2.386172] usb 1-2: Product: HUAWEI_MOBILE
[    2.386175] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: HUAWEI_MOBILE
[    2.560483] usb-storage 1-2:1.2: USB Mass Storage device detected
[    2.562012] hidraw: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
[    2.566924] scsi host3: usb-storage 1-2:1.2
```

**Output of command** `sudo usb_modeswitch -v 12d1 -p 14dc -J -R -W`

```
Take all parameters from the command line


* usb_modeswitch: handle USB devices with multiple modes
* Version 2.2.5 (C) Josua Dietze 2015
* Based on libusb1/libusbx

! PLEASE REPORT NEW CONFIGURATIONS !

DefaultVendor=  0x12d1
DefaultProduct= 0x14dc
HuaweiNewMode=1
NeedResponse=0

Look for default devices ...
found USB ID 1d6b:0003
found USB ID 12d1:14dc
vendor ID matched
product ID matched
found USB ID 80ee:0021
found USB ID 1d6b:0002
Found devices in default mode (1)
Access device 003 on bus 001
Current configuration number is 1
Use interface number 0
Error: message endpoint not given or found. Abort
```

Since I haven't dealt before with a modem on linux does anyone has an idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If e3372 is hilink it works as a router, not a modem. You can easily define it by trying to find the e3372 web interface (192.168.1.1 as I remember). It you have a login page for the e3372 then it's the hilink version.